# Group, index, and compute size of consecutive duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, group-by, duplicates

Consider a list of values, which can be anything, for example a dataframe of strings:

```
  Value
0  "a"
1  "b"
2  "b"
3  "c"
4  "d"
5  "e"
6  "e"
7  "e"
8  "f"
9  "f"
```

I would like to produce two new columns (in an efficient manner because my actual dataframe has millions of rows), `grpidx` the local index in the group of consecutive equal values, and `grpsize` the group size in every row of the group:

```
  Value grpidx grpsize
0  "a"     0      1
1  "b"     0      2
2  "b"     1      2
3  "c"     0      1
4  "d"     0      1
5  "e"     0      3
6  "e"     1      3
7  "e"     2      3
8  "f"     0      2
9  "f"     1      2
```

I manage to have approximate results, but there is always something wrong and I don't manage to have the `grpsize` working properly.

Note: I don't want the resulting final dataframe to have any actual group or subindexing (grouping being done only during the calculation as temporaries).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
# group by consecutive values
g = df.groupby(df['Value'].ne(df['Value'].shift()).cumsum())

# enumeration per group
df['grpidx'] = g.cumcount()

# size of each group
df['grpsize'] = g['Value'].transform('size')
```

Output:

```
  Value  grpidx  grpsize
0     a       0        1
1     b       0        2
2     b       1        2
3     c       0        1
4     d       0        1
5     e       0        3
6     e       1        3
7     e       2        3
8     f       0        2
9     f       1        2
```

Comment: For the given example what is the added value of `df.groupby(df['Value'].ne(df['Value'].shift()).cumsum())` over simply `df.groupby('Value')`? `g.groups.values()` would be the same for both, no?

Comment: @ouroboros1 in the title, OP mentions specially consecutive duplicates. Using `df.groupby('Value')` would not be doing this if duplicates are not consecutive.

Comment: Not sure if I follow. I understand that the two would generate different groups if the list did include *non*-consecutive duplicates, but like you say, the OP explicitly says that this particular column does not.

Comment: @ouroboros1 I don't see where OP explicitly mentions this. In any case if there are only unique stretches, OP can indeed use `df.groupby('Value')`. If not or unsure, `df.groupby(df['Value'].ne(df['Value'].shift()).cumsum())` is a safer alternative and shouldn't have a much greater cost ;)

Comment: Right, let me dail back on the 'explictly', I rather took my cue from the title and then "consecutive equal values" in combination with the alphabetical order, but you're right: that does not necessarily imply that e.g. `a` cannot recur further below. Better safe than sorry ;)